# Collapse html table to individual tables by column

Tags: html, css

I have an html table as shown below:

[image: Desktop width table]

I'm wanting to collapse each column for mobile width viewing as per the following image:

[image: mobile width table]

The problem I'm having is the table is collapsing per row and NOT column.  could someone please point me in the right direction, or is there an easier way to achieve this?

Also is it possible to display the table headings 'Entrance 1' etc when collapsed?

I've included my code below, many thanks

HTML:

```
<div id="page-wrap">
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="one"></th>
        <th>Entrance 1</th>
        <th>Entrance 2</th>
        <th>Entrance 3</th>
        <th>Entrance 4</th>
        <th>Entrance 5</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">Option 1</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">Option 2</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">Option 3</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">Option 4</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">Option 5</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>


@media
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

        .one{
        display: none;
    }

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead tr {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    td {
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
    }

    td:before {
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%;
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    /*
    Label the data
    */
    td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Option 1"; }
    td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Option 2"; }
    td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Option 3"; }
    td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Option 4"; }
    td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Option 5"; }

}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
        .one{
        display: none;
    }

    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 320px; }
    }

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
        .one{
        display: none;
    }
    body {
        width: 495px;
    }
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this, you will just have to edit the cell which includes the checkbox's to show which entrance its associated to.

```css
@media
only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

        .one{
        display: none;
    }

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }
    thead{display:none;}

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    thead td {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    td { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    tr {
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
    }

    tr:before {
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%;
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    /*
    Label the data
    */
    tr:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Option 1"; }
    tr:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Option 2"; }
    tr:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Option 3"; }
    tr:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Option 4"; }
    tr:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Option 5"; }
}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
        .one{
        display: none;
    }

    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 320px; }
    }

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
        .one{
        display: none;
    }
    body {
        width: 495px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrap">
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="one"></th>
        <th>Entrance 1</th>
        <th>Entrance 2</th>
        <th>Entrance 3</th>
        <th>Entrance 4</th>
        <th>Entrance 5</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="one">Option 1</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">Option 2</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">Option 3</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">Option 4</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="one">Option 5</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```